# Does SSH server need to be running in a unix style environment on remote client for GIT clone to work?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, openssh

I am tasked to set up a central GIT repo internally for my team.

I'm working on getting this setup on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine. To the best of my knowledge I've set this up correctly.

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.nubaria.com/en/blog/?p=633) but they use CopSSH which isn't free anymore so instead I installed Windows OpenSSH here: [Install-Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH).

On our windows server I've installed and configured the Windows OpenSSH along with GIT. Made the appropriate changes with regards to the environment variables and references needed.

On my local system (also windows) I've installed Putty and generated my public and private keys. The public key has been copied to the server and placed in the correct file. Using putty, I have verified my public/private key authentication is working.

On the server I created a git bare repository in the C: drive like so:

```
cd C:\
mkdir testing.git
git init --bare testing.git
```

I installed GIT on my local machine and run the command:

```
git clone ssh://name@host:port/testing.git
```

I always end up with the output:

```
Cloning into 'testing'...
fatal: ''/testing.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've tried different variations of this command with the same results and moving the testing.git file to the user home directory (C:\Users\name):

```
git clone ssh://name@host:port/c/testing.git
git clone ssh://name@host:port/~/testing.git
```

I've messed with permissions to explicitly give permissions for this user to access that directory.

It seems as though, maybe the git clone command cannot find the folder on the remote server. I started thinking that the SSH server itself needed to be running in a unix like environment like cygwin. Is this my issue? I've seen tutorials/walkthroughs of installing cygwin with openssh and this would be my next attempt.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**
So I went ahead and installed [Bitvise](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-download) with their 30 day trial (to try) and everything works but this is only for 30 days. So this must mean that there is some set up issue with the Windows OpenSSH that I have?

Comment: IF sshd isn't running properly you should get a pause and then an error that says connection is refused.  Since you aren't getting that error, I think that's not the problem

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Right, I don't think there's anything wrong with the authentication. If I try to log in with an unknown user I get `FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server
 sent: publickey,keyboard-interactive)`. Is my issue with the git command using unix style file navigation and it's not working on the remote windows server?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Where I've used ssh with git on Windows, I just used the tools that were bundled with the "git for windows" package. (In the git bash environment, openssh is available...)  But also I was using a TFS-hosted repo, so filesystem paths weren't an issue.  Have you checked what path comes up as the cwd if you just ssh to the server?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger If I log into the server using putty I don't have a cwd command but I have pwd which I used before. This gives me back /cygdrive/c/Users/name. I've tried using this as the path to the testing.git folder with no luck. I just tried it again to make sure.